# NSStackView and content hugging priority

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nsstackview

`NSStackView` has 2 additional priorities compared to a regular `NSView`, namely `clippingResistancePriority` and `huggingPriority.` The documentation provides a somewhat reasonable explanation what they're for and what they do.

But 4 priorities is a bit overkill.

Now, in said documentation they mention:

> A stack view has no intrinsic content size and does not have a configurable content compression resistance. Calling the `setContentCompressionResistancePriority:forOrientation:` method on a stack view has no effect.

However, `contentHuggingPriority` is left in the shadows.
It seems like `NSStackView` doesn't react to this one as well - or at least I wasn't able to make it do.

Could anybody please confirm or disprove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The inherited content constraint priorities from NSView:

`- (NSLayoutPriority)contentHuggingPriorityForOrientation:(NSLayoutConstraintOrientation)orientation NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_7);
- (NSLayoutPriority)contentCompressionResistancePriorityForOrientation:(NSLayoutConstraintOrientation)orientation NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_7);`

only apply to the constraints created based on the view's `intrinsicContentSize`, which NSStackView does not have. So like you and the documentation mention, they have no effect. 
(unless you subclass NSStackView and override `intrinsicContentSize` to give it some value...)

Comment: Thanks. Hey, while we're at it, maybe you could help clarify smth else about `NSStackView`s? Like this piece of documentation: "To allow view clipping, set a clipping resistance lower than the default value of `NSLayoutPriorityRequired` and set the visibility priority of all the stack view’s views to `NSStackViewVisibilityPriorityMustHold`". This is not true at all. For me the stack view only starts clipping and hiding subviews when clipping resistance is <500. Maybe you have some insights about things like this and where (apart from wwdc, ugh) they can be clarified?

Comment: That clipping resistance priority plays into the rest of the priorities of constraints in the window. So you're right that it's not strictly true that all it takes is < Required, but it's that point when it becomes possible to clip and then just depends on the priorities of the other constraints the stack view is interacting with. The 500 # makes it sounds like your stack view is being sized against the size of the window since the DragThatCanResizeWindow priority is 510 and WindowSizeStayPut is 500.

Comment: The auto layout guide goes into priorities a bit (but not the macOS specific ones): https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW19 . The various NSLayoutPriority constants also have header comments describing their values and semantic meanings